# encrypting messages in php codiegniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, encryption, content-management-system

I am working on an educational website in PHP Condeigniter. The project includes an option where students can sent private messages to tutors and vice versa but they are not allowed to share their contact details with each other, like phone number, skype id, home address, email etc. Is there any way in which I can control this? For example, if a user writes his phone number like 12345677, the algorithm should automatically replace it with xxxxxxxx so that the other user should not be able to view the number..

Comment: You need to come up with a clear set of rules/patterns that you want to obfuscate first. You say you want 12345677 blocked, but what about 123-45677? Or 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 7? Or one two three four five six seven seven? And that's just one part of what you say you want to do.

Comment: The requirement is non-sensical because it can not be achieved, users will find a way around it and it will cause issues for  acceptable messages (false positives). Just tell who ever came up with the concept it won't really work. Consider the security in "myEmail at server dot com", how well has that worked? Finally building a false sense of security is never a good idea.

Answer (score 1):

You can attempt to censor some of the text patterns with [regular expressions](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php) but don't expect to get 100% of them. I don't think you can reliably censor things like skype IDs and addresses.

Also note that if they'll really want to share contact information they are going to find a way to get around your filters.

Comment: There is also the problem of interference with valid communications.